# Mocking fromEvent scroll event on body (or specific element) for unit test case

Tags: angular, unit-testing

Need to write unit test case for below private function which is called on `ngOninit()`

```
private enableBackToTop(): void {

    const elmRef = document.querySelector('.faq-overlay .mat-dialog-container') || document.body;
    fromEvent(elmRef, 'scroll')
        .pipe(
            takeUntil(this.unsubscribe),
            debounceTime(200)
        )
        .subscribe(() => {
            this.isScrollButtonVisible = elmRef.scrollTop > 100;
            this.cdRef.detectChanges();
        });
}
```